# Chrome jquery .animate() leaves 'movement' lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I have a div, so that when I click, it will toggle to expand, or retract. It works pretty well on all browsers, though there is a thing that intrigues me. On Google Chrome when it retracts it leaves small lines from the movement.
[www.rezoluz.com/login.php - The page](http://rezoluz.com/login.php)

To see it, open that page with Google Chrome. And click on the register button twice, on the second time it will leave lines, normally, but not on other browsers. I'm using a standard .animate, with jquery. All help is greatly appreciated.

SCREENSHOT:

[image: See the lines beneath]

Also, here is a jsfiddle showing the result : http://jsfiddle.net/rwQPu/2/ . Error in Chrome 21.0.1180.81 beta-m Win7.

Comment: I can reproduce in Chrome Version 21.0.1180.79 on OSX, and have seen similar artefacts elsewhere from time to time.

Comment: I can't see it on your site, but I have seen weird animation issues like that in chrome lately.

Comment: Please include the particular code in question here. Also it is helpful if you create an example using a tool such as [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that includes a small focused test case.

Comment: For anyone that doesn't see it: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/717/23053889.png/

Comment: Seems fine in my version of Chrome (21.0.1180.79), but I know I had a issue with this in Chrome on a different PC yesterday. A known work around is to define the border and background of the elements that are moving in CSS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bug of chrome. See a previously asked question here :

[**Odd “shaking” effect when animating width with jQuery (only in Chrome!)**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761476/odd-shaking-effect-when-animating-width-with-jquery-only-in-chrome)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a coding problem but actually a bug in certain versions of Google Chrome, as unlikely that may sound.
There is no fix as far a I know, we just need to wait for Google to resolve their problem, knowing Google that will be done from the moment they find out about it.

Comment: it's about a year and the issue is still there

Comment: **May 5, 2013** still there.

Comment: Oct 6 2013 and it is still there jquery 1.10.3

Comment: May 19 2014, still seeing trails in Chrome Version 34.0.1847.137

Comment: August 4 2014, bug still present. 2 years now... Come on Google!