# CSS3 transform rotate causing 1px shift in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I'm having an issue in chrome with a css3 transform rotate transition. The transition is working fine but just after it finishes the element shifts by a pixel. The other strange thing is that it only happens when the page is centered (`margin:0 auto;`). The bug is still there if you remove the transition as well.

You can see it happening here:

http://jsfiddle.net/MfUMd/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <img src="https://github.com/favicon.ico" class="target" alt="img"/>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
    <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap {
    margin:50px auto;
    width: 100px;
}
.block {
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    background:black;
}
.target,.block {
    display:block;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.target:hover,.block:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); 
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg); 
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);  
}
```

Comment out the `margin:0 auto;` line to make it go away.

Anyone have any ideas of how to stop this while keeping the page centered?

I'm using Version 24.0.1312.57 on OSX 10.6.8

Cheers

Comment: I don't notice a shift in the block. Is it happening to the block as well?

Comment: Not able to reproduce either in Chrome 24.0.1312.57

Comment: it happens for both, shifts 1px up just after the transition finishes

Comment: I'm seeing it on Chrome 24 for OSX - it's very noticeable

Comment: It seems to have stopped for me now, no idea why

Comment: ... other people are telling me it's still happening for them so seems it's a temperamental chrome issue

Comment: I can confirm your findings. At first I saw the issue but after multiple tests I no longer saw the shift.

Comment: I'm seeing this issue in Chrome 25, but not in 22. Has anyone submitted a bug report for it? http://dev.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines

Comment: I reported it through "tools > report an issue" in chrome. if you want to test and report in chromium go for it

Comment: I checked this in Chrome 26 and 27, and it seems to be fixed.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Actually just add this to the site container which holds all the elements:
`-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;`

Should fix it!

Gino

Comment: That's beautiful, thank you! It didn't work for me as is but adding the vendor prefix fixed it.

Comment: Thanks! I was having the same issue with 1px shifts when I was doing simple opacity transitions in Chrome. Adding -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden to the container cured everything.

Comment: Edited the answer to include the `-webkit-` prefix. Previously it did not, hence the comments above.

Comment: Awesome! this fixed a very pesky isuue I had with a TranslateY element on hover. For unknown reasons subsequent `<a>` elements were shifted 1px right to come back to position an istant after. Was drivin me nuts.. though is there any info on WHY this happens and WHY is this the fix for it? Anyway thank god I've found your answer, +100 if I could!

Comment: Right... I assumed people would add the webkit since it was a webkit fix... Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I've encountered this a few times and it baffled me. This fixed it! +1

Comment: Does anyone know why this work? I feel strange putting things into my css without understanding them.

Comment: This happened to me in Firefox too, so I'm not sure this is just a Chrome thing.

Comment: I've used this successfully in the past but on my current project it doesn't work.

Comment: This fix helps with the gap, but text and the borders of the divs become blurry. (Chrome v79.0.3945.130 - WIN 10)

Answer (score 22):

I had the same issue, I fixed it by adding the following to the css of the div that is using the transition:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1.0, 1.0);
```

Backface is used for 3D-based transitions but if you are only using 2D there is no need for the extra stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the complement with `transform`, this answer solved my issue.

Comment: Holy crap, this worked on a totally unrelated transform I was trying; but since you mentioned "3D based transitions", I gave it a shot. Lo and behold...

Thanks!

Comment: @FredK: Just add it to your list of transform values. Adding `translateZ(0)` was enough in my case.

Answer (score 3):

`will-change: transform;` on the element helped to me in **2022** (Chrome). No more 1px shift of the text inside the element after zoom animation.

Comment: Impossible! But it helped in Oct, 2023 for the latest Chrome!

Answer (score 0):

there is something unusual in the relation between the body dimension and the structure of the transform. I don't in fact is because the fiddle iframe that contains the preview of the code.

Anyway, I will suggest this approach instead:

```
body{
  width:100%;
  float:left;
}

.wrap {
  margin: 50px 45%;
  width: 5%;
  float: left;
}
.block {
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  background:black;
}
.target,.block {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.target:hover,.block:hover {
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); 
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg); 
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);  
}
```

Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MfUMd/60/)

Answer (score 0):

For 3d transform use this instead:

```
-webkit-transform: perspective(1px) scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1);
transform: perspective(1px) scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1);
```