# Elements shakes during use jQuery.animate()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the example (works in Chrome, for this example I used only webkit prefixes):

```
Visit http://jsfiddle.net/HgJun/1/
```

I faced with the following situation:

Animation at a given time is applied to two elements. Blocks are animated simultaneously, for the same period of time using the jQuery.animate().

1) unit class "inner" changes transform: translateY coordinate 
2) block with class "content" changes the height

While the animation is used, children of the block "footer" start to shake a little (vibrate), moving up and down to 1px or 2px.

This situation was observed with the following conditions:

Windows 8
Chrome 30
Firefox 24

Perhaps someone has already solved a similar problem?

Comment: Where is your Jquery animate code?

Comment: I made the update, JQuery code, see above. I apologize, but I can not give a real example of the code, as this situation applies to a large project and the code hard to integrate services such as jsfiddle.

Comment: [CSS3 transform rotate causing 1px shift in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14729492/css3-transform-rotate-causing-1px-shift-in-chrome) this is not an answer to my question. I tried it `backface-visibility: hidden;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
perspective: 1000;`, but it did not help