# Odd behaviour with two SVG images in Chrome, after pressing back the images swap places

Tags: css, google-chrome, web, svg, embed

I am not sure what's going on and whether it's due to CSS or SVG meta, I would think the latter. But if you go to the site and browse to any of the links on the top menu and then press the back button, Chrome will render the svg file data in the wrong object tags and not apply the css rules. Please note this does not happen every time, maybe on second or 3rd go. Using the latest Chrome release. This happens only on Chrome and Chrome mobile.

http://ecww-ru.1gb.ru/

The SVG files are embedded as follows:

```
  <object data="/Content/images/master/wwlogotext.svg" type="image/svg+xml" class="logotext">

      <img src="/Content/images/master/wwlogotext.gif" id="logotext" class="logotext" />

  </object>
```

Comment: Seems to be reported as a bug in Chrome here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=352762

Answer (score 1):

I was also a little bit lost with this but this adding this `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` to the wrapper of the svg work for me.

You can read more about this here: [CSS3 transform rotate causing 1px shift in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14729492/css3-transform-rotate-causing-1px-shift-in-chrome)