# transform: translateY(-50%) causes 1px jump/shift in IE and EDGE

Tags: css, css-transitions

Please see an example in jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/0uwmxt02/1/

In IE and EDGE the transform: translateY(-50%) causes 1px jump up and down at the start and end of the animation. In Chrome the displacement still occurs but it is smooth. Any idea of what causes it?

```css
.submenu-arrow-hover {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  top:50px;
 }
  
 .submenu-arrow-hover:after {
    //background: rgba(155, 173, 188, 0.9);
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    width: 1px;
    height: 28px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-right:0;
    border-top:0;
    top:50%;
    right:-1px;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    transition-duration: .3s;
  }
  
.submenu-arrow-hover:hover::after {
      //background: rgba(155, 173, 188, 0.9);
      position:absolute;
      content:'';
      width: 20px;
      height:20px;
      border: 1px solid red;
      border-right:0;
      border-top:0;
      top:50%;
      right:-1px;
      transform-origin: 0 0;
      transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="submenu-arrow-hover">HOVER ME</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to use jQuery as elements will have variable height and the arrow position needs to be adjusted when the screen is resized and when elements change size/position.

```
    function setMargins(arrow) {
    parentHeight = $(arrow).parent().height();  
    arrowHeight = $(arrow).height();  
    topMargin = (parentHeight - (arrowHeight - 1)) / 2 ;    
    $(arrow).css("margin-top", topMargin);    
}


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.submenu-arrow-hover--arrow').each(function() {
    setMargins(this);
})
});

// timeout function needed as there is transition on the menu elements so
// function has to fire few milliseconds after the transitions have finished animating

$(window).resize(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
    $('.submenu-arrow-hover--arrow').each(function() {

        setMargins(this)            
    })    
}, 600);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Appears to be some kind of confusion between the translation and rotation. As a workaround, try removing the `translateY()` requirement completely:

```css
.submenu-arrow-hover {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  top: 50px;
  
  /* outline and excess height added as a test */
  outline: 1px dotted #ccc;
  height: 100px;
}

.submenu-arrow-hover::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 1px;
  height: 28px;
  border: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid red;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  right: -1px;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transition-duration: .3s;
  
  /* position top of pseudo element halfway down */
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -14px; /* accurately centre by offsetting by half the height */
}

.submenu-arrow-hover:hover::after {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-bottom-color: red;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="submenu-arrow-hover">HOVER ME</div>
```

**EDIT**: updated to ensure arrow is centred vertically within parent `<div/>`.

Comment: I need the translateY though, to position the arrow horizontally exactly in the middle of the parent div.

Comment: because the elements will have variable height (eg folding into two lines when screen size is reduced) I can't use pixel values. I ended up having to use jQuery to dynamically adjust the position...

Answer (score 1):

- Equal `.submenu-arrow-hover:after`'s `height` to `.submenu-arrow-hover:hover::after`'s (`20px`), otherwise the height async will make it bounce.

```css
.submenu-arrow-hover {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  top: 50px;
}

.submenu-arrow-hover:after {
  //background: rgba(155, 173, 188, 0.9);
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 1px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-right: 0;
  border-top: 0;
  top: 50%;
  right: -1px;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition-duration: .3s;
}

.submenu-arrow-hover:hover::after {
  //background: rgba(155, 173, 188, 0.9);
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-right: 0;
  border-top: 0;
  top: 50%;
  right: -1px;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="submenu-arrow-hover">HOVER ME</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For Chrome, [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15623914/3705191) worked wonderfully!

Add this to the element that has translateY applied: `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;`